# How to make Async Api Requests in Python, properly?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am not an expert in python so I am having trouble trying to make async api requests, it's throwing "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed".

I make lots of requests to an API and sometimes it returns status code 429 (too many requests), so what I want is when it happens I want to keep trying the request until it returns status code 200 and continue the process.

```
import requests
import asyncio
import aiohttp

CONCURRENCY = 3
TIMEOUT = 40000

async def fetch(session, sem, obj):
    async with sem:
        async with session.get(obj['url'], headers={}, params={}) as resp:
            #print(await response.json())

            if resp.status == 429: # too many consecutive requests
                print('Too many requests. Waiting some seconds to continue...')
                await sleep(5)

                while True:
                    r = await requests.get(obj['url'], auth=('xxxxx',''))
                    if r.status != 429:
                        break
                    await sleep(6)

                return await r


async def call_api(list_obj):
    try:
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENCY)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth(login='xxxxx', password='')) as session:
                responses = await asyncio.gather(*(
                    asyncio.wait_for(fetch(session, sem, i), TIMEOUT)
                    for i in list_obj
        ))

        return responses
    except :
        logger.critical('API request problem: ' + traceback.format_exc())



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(call_api(array))
data = loop.run_until_complete(future)
loop.close()
```

It throws "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed".

Comment: What? You're getting rate-limited, so you want to keep hitting the API with more requests?

Comment: In fact, after receiving the 429 I would sleep a certain amount of time and try again, if it returns 429 again then i would wait a little more and do it again to check if it is already 200 status code